# Каким однокоренным словом проверить правописание слова "подражать"?

Tags: орфография

Каким однокоренным словом проверить правописание слова "подражать"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Подражать** - однокоренное (исторически и фактически) слово с **образом**, не так ли? Подражают обычно какому-либо ***образцу***. Ищем и легко находим однокоренную форму с ударением в нужном месте: **о/без/об/рАж/у**. Также -    **обрАзчик**. 
Так что это не "словарное слово", а проверяемое - если немного покопаться в закромах РЯ.

Исправление и дополнение.

Меня ввела в заблуждение "авторитетная" статья из этимологического словаря Шапошникова. Прошу прощения за это псевдонаучное академическое издание!
[image: Подражать] 
Заглянул в старый добрый САР 1789-94 и нашел подтверждение другой своей версии : родственными являются слова дразнить (дражнить), подражать и раздражать, разумеется. Старинное слово ***подрагъ*** означает в одном из своих смыслов - подобие, сходство (другое значение - подол, кайма).
Слово дорога, по мнению составителей САР, относится к другой опере... Я думаю так же.
Проверочное слово к *подражать* : передрАзнивать.

Comment: Плюс. Но: что есть Слово с образом?

Comment: @shampar в ответе сказано "**образ** является однокоренным словом к слову **подражать**", если вы об этом.

Comment: Слово "образ" известно в языке с XI века со значением "вид, облик, изображение, икона", старшее значение - нечто, получившее новый облик, вид (из словаря Черных) Родственные слова - разить и резать. Слово "подражать" заимствовано из старославянского языка в XV веке (от драга - дорога). Таким образом,  слово подражать не может мотивироваться словом "образ", в нем нельзя выделить приставку ПОД и исторический корень РАЗ (без приставки ОБ, входящей в "образ")

Comment: Исправил свой ответ! Но *дорога* - это не мотивировка для *подражания*,  как я считаю.

Comment: Я посмотрела в словарях этимологию глагола дразнить. Шанский считает родственными драть - раздражать - дразнить (от дразнь). Черных  говорить примерно о том же: дразнить от раздражать, натирать кожу. О подобии у этих авторов нет речи.

Answer (score 1):

Это непроверяемая безударная гласная — здесь проверить никак не получится.

Answer (score 1):

"Подражать" - словарное слово.

"Подражать" - следовать примеру, образцу, делать что-то в подражание кому-то, брать с кого-то пример, стараться уподобиться. А ещё есть слово "подр**о**жать" от слова "дрожь".

Answer (score 1):

Подражать - идти той же дорогой (по Шанскому),чередование ОРО/РА, сравнить: ворота - вратарь, горожанин - гражданин, городить - оградить.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос вызвал бурную дискуссию, в ходе которой прозвучало несколько интересных соображений, но, боюсь, не все заметили достойную внимания мысль в ответе @Дерзкий Grantum. Этим приемом я пользуюсь много лет. Проверочное слово для "подражать" — "дра́знит". Это очень близкие, однокоренные слова, ведь "подражает кому-то" — значит "дразнит кого-то".

Comment: Может быть, они кажутся близкими и однокоренными, да только авторитетные этимологические словари это не подтверждают (Шанский, Черных): дразнить - это раздражать, а не подражать.